# Issues creating and finishing activities

Tags: android, android-activity

In my main activity, I create an intent to start activityB. Once the user has done something in activityB, I call `activityB.this.finish()`. the problem is that i see that after `finish()` is called, `onDestroy()` - and probably other activity closing methods - are being called on my activityA.

Additionally, when i click the up button in ActivityB it also has the same problem that it calls `onDestroy()` in my main activity.

This doesn't sound at all right to me and I see on my memory monitor that every time ActivityB calls `finish()`, it allocates another 10-20MB to my app. Obviously I'm doing something wrong; can anyone please tell me how to successfully close an activity which I'm done with, and return to the previous one? Thanks.

Here is code where I finish ActivityB:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    case R.id.action_create:
           // do some work and then finish                
        CreateLocationActivity.this.finish();                
}
```

and then here is where i am logging to see if my main activity gets destroyed:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("DESTROYED", "main activity has been obliterated har har!!");

    // finish up activity:
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreference();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("something", "one");
    editor.putString("something2", "two");
    editor.putInt("number", 1);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I just tested a basic example and didn't see the first Activity being destroyed.  Can you show your code where you start Activity B, and where you call `finish()`?

Comment: Now i actually see it getting destroyed ONLY when up button is pressed ??

Comment: Strange.  Is there anything else in the logs that could be of help?  Something isn't right.  Maybe you have an exception somewhere?

Comment: yeah im doing something real wrong because right now for example, i put a log method in the onCreate in the mainActivity, and it logged four times - i believe im not closing things up properly, and i have triples of activities floating around.

Comment: Is `CreateLocationActivity` the `Activity` you call ActivityB? Also, what does `// do some work and then finish` actually do in your `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` method?

Comment: yes sorry if i didn't explain well enough. What Im doing there is that creating an object and then displaying that object in a list in my main activity.

Comment: Does Activity A actually re-create successfully when you go back to it?  Or is your app closing?

Comment: I am getting what i expect when i am navigated back towards my main activity from ActivityB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is almost the correct behavior. Excerpts from the following link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

> There are a few of key scenarios in which your activity is stopped and restarted:
>   •The user opens the Recent Apps window and switches from your app to another app. The activity in your app that's currently in the foreground is stopped. If the user returns to your app from the Home screen launcher icon or the Recent Apps window, the activity restarts.
>   •**The user performs an action in your app that starts a new activity. The current activity is stopped when the second activity is created. If the user then presses the Back button, the first activity is restarted.**
>   •The user receives a phone call while using your app on his or her phone.

I am assuming you are using startActivity for moving to activity to B. Some help can come from using startActivityForResult.